# Book class \sectionmark not working when section heading is on first page of section

Tags: sectioning, book-design

Firstly, I know that this question has been asked at least twice elsewhere, but in one case the first answer uses memoir class, where it still uses the long version on the first page but wraps it and I don't want that and the second answer is just erroneous. In the other case I found, the first answer is complicated by dealing with the code of a particular solution attempted in the MWE and also has the same second, erroneous answer.

It seems to me the point is to isolate just what the problem is and maybe report it as a bug and motivate getting it fixed at source.

In the mean time, if someone has a good workaround for this bug, it would be much appreciated. I'm coauthoring a text book and we're trying to get it ready for publication and this issue is a big problem.

I have included below a very minimal working example which demonstrates the bug with no other complications in the code, other than using the geometry of our book's page dimensions, hopefully to eliminate that as a cause, so it's clearly not caused by adding in any other packages.

The problem occurs for section 2 in the header on page 3.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{book}

\usepackage[paperheight=22.5cm,paperwidth=15cm, left=15mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[2-1]
\section{This section will be made up of several paragraphs of dummy text}
\sectionmark{Several paragraphs of dummy text}
\lipsum[2-10]
\section{This section will also be made up of several paragraphs of dummy text}
\sectionmark{A lot more dummy text}
\lipsum[2-10]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug but the documented behaviour: The header will show the *first* sectionmark, and as `\section` issues one too, it will win.

Either use the optional argument:

```
\section[A lot more dummy text]{This section will also be made up of several paragraphs of dummy text}
```

Then the short text will also be used in the table of contents.

If you want the long version in table of contents you need a rather convoluted version described in https://texfaq.org/FAQ-runheadtoobig:

```
\section[This section will also be made up of several paragraphs of dummy text]%
  {This section will also be made up of several paragraphs of dummy text\sectionmark{A lot more dummy text}}
\sectionmark{A lot more dummy text}
```

Newer classes like e.g. scrbook have options here which make this easier.

Comment: When you say documented behaviour, whose idea was that? And even with the wrapped version in memoir class it looks bad. So the designer/s of the book class think/s the default should be that you write short section titles? Now that I've been involved in writing a fairly large text book with twelve hefty chapters and lots of appendices I developed some strong opinions about it.

Comment: Well one would have to check history and the sources, but imho this part of the design of the standard classes is from Leslie Lamport himself. We are planing a redesign of the sectioning commands---we need it for the tagging project---and improving the settings for header, bookmarks and toc will part of it, but for now you will have to live with the current state or use a class like scrbook or a package like titlesec which offer more options.

Comment: In my search for info about this problem, I came across another question here where a guy using titlesec was getting into all kinds of problems trying to solve the same problem. I will investigate scrbook. And thanks for your efforts here because at least I now have a definitive answer.